# how to use next and previous button in yii

Tags: php, yii

Hello i am having Yii code for  page number displaying i want to use only

Next and Previous Button How can i achieve this

Here is my code

```
public function getNextId()
{
    $record=self::model()->find(array(
            'condition' => 'id>:current_id',
            'order' => 'id ASC',
            'limit' => 1,
            'params'=>array(':current_id'=>$this->id),
    ));
    if($record!==null)
        return $record->id;
    return null;
}
public function getPreviousId()
{
    $record=self::model()->find(array(
            'condition' => 'id<:current_id',
            'order' => 'id DESC',
            'limit' => 1,
            'params'=>array(':current_id'=>$this->id),
    ));
    if($record!==null)
        return $record->id;
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want To add custom pageingnation in website Then this is the basic code of Controller

```
function actionIndex(){
$query = User::find()->where(['status' => 1]);
$countQuery = clone $query;
$pages = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $countQuery->count()]);
$models = $query->offset($pages->offset)
    ->limit($pages->limit)
    ->all();

return $this->render('index', [
     'models' => $models,
     'pages' => $pages,
]);}
```

For view add this code

```
foreach ($models as $model) { // Do model Code
} echo LinkPager::widget([    'pagination' => $pages,]);
```

For read more get this link : http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/custom-pagination-in-yiiframework-2-0/